# How to list all hosting services on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, port, hosts

I cannot host on port 80, because there is an application on the background, which hosts on port 80. How do I find out which program it is?

Comment: Port 80 is http port by default. So first of all, close all programs that use http (such as browsers, IM software and so on). Also I wouldn't recomend using this port in your program (unless it's a browser or smtg like it).

Comment: @SEARAS Let's not confuse the source and destination ports. Browsers use 80 port as destination port.

Comment: On a standard home computer it's often Skype, so before attempting any solutions listed below I suggest you check that first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get local application `ProcessID` use port 80:

```
netstat -aon | findstr "LISTENING" | find /i ":80" | more
```

var 2:

```
netstat -aon | find /i ":80" | more
```

Get application command line:

```
Wmic process where (ProcessId=<you application ProcessID>)  get Commandline, ProcessId
```

Get service command line:

```
wmic Service where (ProcessID=<you application ProcessID>) Get Caption, Name, StartMode, State, PathName, ProcessId,  StartName
```

[Portqry 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) test port 80:

```
Portqry -local -wport 80 | findstr "LISTENING"
```

[Portqry](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326) Support Tools test port 80 UDP and TCP:

```
Portqry -n 192.168.20.10 -p BOTH -e 80 -i -s
```

GUI [TCPView v3.05](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437):

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

`cmd`:
[image: cmd]

Far manager:
[image: Far manager]

Far manager get Service command line, PID:

[image: Far manager get Service command line, PID]

Comment: It's linux terminal command. I tried it in cmd.exe, but windows can't find the command

Comment: Not. `Cmd` and Far Manager at Microsoft Windows. See pic.

Comment: @IterAtor both `netstat` and `wmic` commands are working in `cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Open command promt and type

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

that will show you all open ports and the process IDs associated with them. There you can find the PID which is responsible for port 80 being taken and find that PID in Task Manager.